# jquery datepicker needs one last tweak

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

Last one for today, I promise!  :o)

Does anyone know which css tag is causing both the words (Prev, Next) and the buttons to appear?  I want to get rid of the words and just show the arrows for Prev/Next.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on the class `ui-icon` there should be this style `text-indent: -99999px;`

Comment: Do you know any site that lists all the possible options and what they control?